# SameSite Cookie Changes in ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core

Tags: samesite

Do I need to upgrade from 4.0 to 4.7.2 - Yes ,
Build you solution with .net target framework 4.7.2
update web.config
compilation targetFramework 4.7.2
httpRuntime targetFramework 4.7.2
update samesite option to Strict, Lax, or None as per your application requirement
httpCookie.SameSite to SameSiteMode.Lax

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2019/05/10/chrome-browser-pushes-samesite-cookie-security-overhaul/

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "***Do i need to upgrade from 4.0 to 4.7.2??***", then Yes, you have to upgrade the Framework to sameSite attribute work.

I have tried lot of hacks but none of it works actually, at the end i upgraded Framework to **4.7.2** and added below in the Web.Config to make it work.

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
```